# How to Iterate through List of Objects, passing to method then store return value in array list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I want to iterate through a List of Team objects, each object has a string and three integers within it. I want to pass it to a method which will compare the first Team object with the second one, then second to third and so on, Then finally get the returned enumerator depending on the comparison and store it into an array list.

This is what I have so far, but when I run it, it comes up with a null value exception.

```
TeamList = leagueRepository.getTeamList();
    int i = 0;

    for(Team team: teamList) {
        TeamStatus teamStatus = team.leagueStatus(team, team);
        verdictArray.add(i, teamStatus);
```

How do I get the first and second Team objects in the List?

Comment: What is `verdictArray` and how do you declare and initialize it.

Comment: sounds like sorting these objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `TeamList` is a `List` you can call `get(0)` to get the first entry and `get(1)` to get the second entry.

If you only want to sort the list you can take a look at this post

[Java List Sorting: Is there a way to keep a list permantly sorted automatically like TreeMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903611/java-list-sorting-is-there-a-way-to-keep-a-list-permantly-sorted-automatically)

Comment: Yup. This is the answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first and second objects in a list, you should use `list.get(0)` and `list.get(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to iterate using an index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    Team current = list.get(i);
    Team next = list.get(i + 1);
    // do something with current and next
}
```

You could also store the previous element at each iteration:

```
Team previous = null;
for (Team current : list) {
    if (previous != null) {
        // do something with previous and current
    }
    previous = current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing but sorting. If youe use **Collections.sort with comparator** you can achieve this.