# Data Structure - Avoid Duplicate in List and Map

Tags: java

I have a million Employee Objects in a List. The Employee Objects get modified and also sorted many times while processing. Also, while processing, there is a need to fetch Employee objects by Department. Means, I have to maintain a Map with Department as Key and List as value.

While processing, the RAM shoots up to 100+ GB. Whereas, the Employess per se on a file is about 2 GB.

List is the master, while Map is there for convenience (to fetch by Department).

Now, my question is: How can I avoid duplication of Employee objects in List & Map? Whenever a getByDept is called, if I loop through List it's expensive & time consuming.

I need a Map with List as  backing data. Any changes to the Employee object in List should reflect in the Map too.

Any ideas to build a data structure without duplicating Employee objects in Map?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say you need to elaborate a bit and show some code. Maps and lists only contain _references_ to objects that are stored on the heap so if you have a `Map<Department, Employee>` and `List<Employee>` both structures can easily reference the same `Employee` instances and any changes to such an instance are "reflected" in both.

Comment: Also note that a 2GB file can result in much higher memory requirements when loaded into objects so it would be necessary to analyze that. If you load the entire file into _one_ list only and the heap usage is much lower than when you're using the map this could indicate you're creating multiple instances of the same employee - if so try to eliminate that. Additionally you might want to acquire and analyze a heap dump to see where the memory goes - maps can be quite costly if used wrong.

Comment: Firstly you should have a valid equals() and hashCode() method for the Emploee class. Given that you should check to use something different than just a List. For example SQLite. So you can enforce constraint and handle the data efficiently in memory.

Comment: You should have a reference on the Emploee about the department they belong, or you have a different source for this information? In this last case you're in trouble as you have to cover the case an Emploee cannot belong to multiple department.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a `List`:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements

Adding two times the same element in the set doesn't change the set.

Remember to define the methods `equals` (and `hashcode`) to use correctly a `Set` because they are used internally by the `Set` methods.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP means duplicate entries but rather avoiding that there are 2 instances - one in the list and one in the map. That's at least how I understand the question.

Comment: Yes go for set instead of list only maintains the unique data

Comment: When I "add, modify or delete" an Employee object to the List, I need it to be reflected in the Map also.

Answer (score 1):

Add your list to a empty set, that will remove all the duplicate elements of your employee list. The you can again convert back the set to list like this. The following removes the duplicate elements from List using set. Then using the non duplicate employees, your search will become faster.

```
      Map<Integer, List> employeeMap = new HashMap<Integer, List>();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Allen");
        list.add("Alder");
        list.add("Allen");
        set.addAll(list);
        //This removes duplicate
        List<String> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        employeeList.addAll(set);
        //Add to the Map
        employeeMap.put(1, employeeList);
        //the way to edit the list directly, but you cannot check for duplicate elemets here
        employeeMap.get(1).add("werner");        
        // Instead of List use Set
        Map<Integer, Set> employeeMapUsingSet = new HashMap<Integer, Set>();
        Set<String> employeeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        List<String> employeeLists = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Allen");
        list.add("Alder");
        list.add("Allen");
        employeeSet.addAll(list);                
        //Add to the set to Map
        employeeMapUsingSet.put(1, employeeSet);
        //the way to edit the list directly, but you cannot check for duplicate elemets here
        employeeMapUsingSet.get(1).add("werner");
        //the following Duplicate will not be allowed and Map also gets updated, so no need for reference variable
        employeeMapUsingSet.get(1).add("Alder");
        //Again add Nancy to the set added in map and print
        employeeSet.add("Nancy");
        //This will print Nancy with the result too, because we are stroing a copy of pointer in the map, so the changes get reflected
        System.out.println(employeeMapUsingSet.get(1));
```

Try this because we are storing a pointer for employee set in the map, any changes made in the employee set will reflect on the Map too. TreeSet has been used for sorting purpose. Untill you assign employeeSet again to new TreeSet, the address will be the same, so any changes made will reflect in the map too. Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is not about Employee objects in a List. The Employee objects are in a List. However, since I need to fetch Employee objects frequently (about 100 from a total of 1 million) by Department Id, I am forced to use a map with Department Id as Key and List<Employees> as value.

Comment: Updated my answer, It may help you.

Comment: Thanks Venkat. I got you. Let me rephrase my question. I have a million Employee objects created. Each Employee gets added to the List. While Employees are being created, I also need to have Employees grouped by Department Id - so that, I can fetch list of employees efficiently. Now the contents of this grouped Map should always be in sync with the List. Should I go with a Listener on the List?

Comment: Again updated the code with some more explanation. In the bottom of the solution find explanation about map using the reference of the set.

Answer (score 0):

"sorted many times" is possibly the source of the memory usage, depending on how you go about it.

e.g. List.sort creates a new array containing all list elements, each time you sort.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid duplication of Employee objects in List & Map?
>   Whenever a getByDept is called, if I loop through List it's expensive
>   & time consuming.

Maps and list contains references of the object in heap memory created by JVM. So, as soon as you add or remove some employee from list, since map is pointing to same list, you will get the updated list from map. Below is example to illustrate this fact:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<Integer, List<Employee>> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Employee> empList1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList1.add(new Employee(3,"c",13));
        empList1.add(new Employee(2, "b", 12));
        empList1.add(new Employee(1, "a", 11));

        List<Employee> empList2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList2.add(new Employee(6,"f",16));
        empList2.add(new Employee(5, "e", 15));
        empList2.add(new Employee(4, "d", 14));

        hashMap.put(101, empList1);
        hashMap.put(102, empList2);

        System.out.println("Before::::::::::");
        hashMap.forEach((x, y)-> System.out.println(x + " " + y));

        List<Employee> list = hashMap.get(101);
        list.add(new Employee(10, "z", 18));

        System.out.println("After::::::::::");
        hashMap.forEach((x, y)-> System.out.println(x + " " + y));
    }
}

class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;
    public Employee(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + " : " + name + " : " + age;
    }
}
```

> Any ideas to build a data structure without duplicating Employee
>   objects in Map?

Since you need to remove duplicates and also sort the list multiple times, better approach would be to use `TreeSet`.

Advantage of using `TreeSet` is that, you will get distinct employees and also you will have employees in sorted order.

Answer (score 0):

`sorted many times while processing`

You haven't mentioned based on what condition you are sorting. To solve your problem you can sort based on department, so that all the objects having same department are grouped together.

To fetch list of objects based on department, you can use binary search to find the start and end index of the department range. time complexity O(log(n)). This way you don't need to maintain map and makes the logic simpler.

```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        search(List.of(1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8), 4);
    }
    
    private static void search(List<Integer> list, int searchKey) {
        int left = 0, right = list.size() - 1;
        int firstOccurrence = findFirstOccurrence(list, left, right, searchKey);
        int lastOccurrence = findLastOccurrence(list, left, right, searchKey);
        System.out.println("left: " + firstOccurrence + " right: " + lastOccurrence);
    }
    
    private static int findFirstOccurrence(List<Integer> list, int left, int right, int searchKey) {
        while (left <= right) {
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            if (list.get(mid) < searchKey) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                right = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return left;
    }
    
    private static int findLastOccurrence(List<Integer> list, int left, int right, int searchKey) {
        while (left <= right) {
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            if (list.get(mid) <= searchKey) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                right = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return right;
    }
```

When adding any object or updating department for an object you need to re-sort using https://stackoverflow.com/a/4903642/9160306 which takes O(log(n)) time and O(1) space.

Overall time complexity add/remove/update - O(log(n))

Overall Space complexity add/remove/update - O(1)